# Simple JOIN in SQL

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL thus the question. Here are my two tables.

```
persons
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| given_name  | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| family_name | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

courses

+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| teacher_id | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name       | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here's my simple JOIN statement,

```
mysql> SELECT id, given_name, family_name FROM persons, courses WHERE courses.teacher_id = persons.id;
```

Here's what i get as an error,

```
ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous
```

What am I doing wrong here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: which id do you want? persons.id or courses.id?

Comment: What is you expected result ? id is on both tables and you are doing implicit join and without alias you are selecting the id and hence the error.

Comment: Where's the `JOIN` in your `JOIN statement`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your query in the following way:

```
SELECT persons.id, given_name, family_name 
FROM persons, courses 
WHERE courses.teacher_id = persons.id;
```

or

```
SELECT courses.id, given_name, family_name 
FROM persons, courses 
WHERE courses.teacher_id = persons.id;
```

depending if you want the id of the course or that of the person.

Answer (score 0):

Include teacher foreign key in the person table to creat relationship between the teacher and the person. 
E.g. Many students is taught by a teacher